# How can grails "dependency error" be resolved?

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-2.2

Grails was running fine till I decided to re-install it:
Its now started showing up the below error during "run-app" or create-app command process-

- Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information): - org.grails.plugins:tomcat:2.2.1

### Details

> UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
>   org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.2.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.2.1 {build=[default]}:invalid end of token at position 46 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Documents/Startup/App-resources/1] grails development/Sandbox & Archive/emote reboot/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]

****BuildConfig.groovy***********

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    }
}
```

*******After setting Buildconfig to "Warn"**************************

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: tomcat-2.2.1.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.2.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.2.1 {build=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
| Downloading: jquery-1.8.3.pom.sha1
| Downloading: resources-1.1.6.pom.sha1
| Downloading: database-migration-1.3.2.pom.sha1
| Downloading: zipped-resources-1.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: facebook-graph-0.14.pom.sha1
| Downloading: cache-headers-1.1.5.pom.sha1
| Downloading: cached-resources-1.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: mongodb-1.2.0.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.8.3: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.8.3 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#database-migration;1.3.2: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#database-migration;1.3.2 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#zipped-resources;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#zipped-resources;1.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#facebook-graph;0.14: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#facebook-graph;0.14 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#cache-headers;1.1.5: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#cache-headers;1.1.5 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#cached-resources;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#cached-resources;1.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#mongodb;1.2.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#mongodb;1.2.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
| Downloading: jquery-1.8.3.pom.sha1
| Downloading: resources-1.1.6.pom.sha1
| Downloading: database-migration-1.3.2.pom.sha1
| Downloading: zipped-resources-1.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: facebook-graph-0.14.pom.sha1
| Downloading: cache-headers-1.1.5.pom.sha1
| Downloading: cached-resources-1.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: mongodb-1.2.0.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.8.3: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.8.3 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#database-migration;1.3.2: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#database-migration;1.3.2 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#zipped-resources;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#zipped-resources;1.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#facebook-graph;0.14: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#facebook-graph;0.14 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#cache-headers;1.1.5: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#cache-headers;1.1.5 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#cached-resources;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#cached-resources;1.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        :: org.grails.plugins#mongodb;1.2.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.grails.plugins#mongodb;1.2.0 {runtime=[default]}:
    invalid end of token at position 22 in pattern /Users/Sanks/Dropbox/1]KeyThemes1/emote/Developer/AppDev/emote/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:2.2.1
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the `project` and `ivy` in `.grails` directory? Have you used `grails clean` and `grails compile` before running app?

Comment: No change in error despite trying the clean and compile commands. Note that I am getting this error regardless of project. It is affecting all new and old grails projects.

Comment: UPDATE- Error resolved.
SOLUTION - Make sure no filepath names do NOT include any special characters - incl "]" as in my case

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Does ticked(accepted) answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

We need to see your BuildConfig.groovy instead of making wild guesses.
My impression is that your resolver pattern doesn't match your layout structure, as it looks like your using an ivy repository.

Do give some more accurate answers, we need to see your *BuildConfig.groovy*... Otherwise, we can only speculate, but your error looks simple to fix, you could also turn on debugging.

In *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*, change the line

```
log "error"
```

to

```
log "debug"
```

After that it should be easy enough for you to fix your problem, if you don't want to paste any code.

---

You're apparently using a custom ivy resolver, maybe your resolver pattern seems wrong.

It could be that you need to quote escape the '&' sign (wild guess). I generally avoid those spaces between folder names or weird characters.

Please post more details about your *BuildConfig.groovy* if the suggestion from @dmahapatro doesn't work.

Comment: I have now improved the folder names. But still no change in error.

Comment: At this point I would suggesting deleting your .grails folder.

Comment: I've tried deleting .grails many times to no avail. I have now added new warning messages output in the original question which might offer  more clues, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your build.config in plugin section

```
compile (":kickstart-with-bootstrap:0.9.6") {
            excludes 'jquery'            
}
```